# Replicate character across whole line on Vim/Neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

I would to write a character, and instantly replicate it across the whole line. How can I write a function that mimics a keyboard shortcut in vim?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean be 'a keyboard shortcut'.

Comment: @mattb hope this helps https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5443/keyboard-shortcut

Answer (score 3):

Go to the start of the line, visually select all the existing characters,
and replace them with the letter x:

`0v$rx`

Or if there are no characters already, you could insert an `x` 80 times in a
row:

`80ix`

An alternative would be to type the letter, then repeat it another 79 times:

`ix`

`79.`

Here's a function that will do it for you (called with `<LEADER>r`):

```
function! RepChar()
    let char = input("character to replicate: ")
    let line_length = &textwidth
    if line_length == 0
        let line_length = input("'textwidth' option not set... how long is a line: ")
    endif
    execute 'normal! '.line_length.'i'.char
endfunction
nnoremap <LEADER>r :call RepChar()<CR>
```

Comment: I was looking for a keyboard shorcut

Comment: @Pyzyryab There isn't a dedicated shortcut in vim to do this. You would have to create a function and then remap some key combination to call that function.

Comment: @Pyzyryab see updated answer.